# How to track number of API requests when using Rack Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, caching, rack

I will be using Rack Cache (with Memcache) to cache responses from an API I am building with Rails. In addition, I need to implement hit counting for the API. Any suggestions on to pull this off? I am guessing it would need to be handled with Rack, but am not sure where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest adding a piece of Rack middleware to the top of your middleware stack which increments a counter for the request path.

For example, to do this with Redis:

```
# lib/request_counter.rb
class RequestCounter
  def self.redis
    @redis ||= Redis.new(host: ENV["REDIS_HOST"], port: ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
  end

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    self.class.redis.incr "request_counter:#{request.fullpath}"
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

# config/application.rb (in the Rails::Application subclass)
require "request_counter"
config.middleware.insert(0, RequestCounter)
```

This would mean that each request to `/path` would increment the Redis key `request_counter:/path`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your production setup, you might be able to do this in one of the following ways

- parse nginx logs, either with your own scripts or using splunk ([example](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-script-monitor-apachenginx-log-file/))
- write your own nginx module to do the counting
- attach your own Rack middleware before Rack::Cache to do the counting ([guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack))